# scrolling div with ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, css

I have built an 1 on 1 support chat with ajax which works great. I have noticed that when ajax refreshes the div, higher than the div height, the div just keeps expanding.. I have noticed many people with the same issue have been advised to use overflow: auto for scrolling which I have tried and doesn't seam to work at all.. could some one point me in the right direction to get working scrollbars in div??

Failing this, my only other choice is to use iframes which i really dont like.

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0"><TR height="90%"><TD width="100%">

<div id="adminlog" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
</TD></TR><TR><TD><textarea rows="4" name="input" id="input" cols="100" style="width: 80%; border:solid 1px orange; background-color: lightyellow;">
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="send" id="send" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return textSubmit();"></TD></TR></TABLE>

<script>
function textSubmit(str) {
if (str != "refresh") {
        var admin = "<?PHP echo $admin;?>";
        var session = "<?PHP echo $session;?>";
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        document.getElementById("input").value = "";
        var dataString = 'admin='+ admin + '&input=' + input + '&session=' + session;
}
else {
        var session = "<?PHP echo $session;?>";
        var dataString = 'session=' + session;
}
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "admin/chatsession.php",
            data: dataString,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $("#adminlog").html(data);
            },
            error: function (){}
        });
    return true;

}

  setInterval('textSubmit("refresh")', 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery

```
<table id="scroll"><!--code--></table>
$(document).ready(function(){
// check if the scroll is down
    var isScrolledDown = ($('#scroll')[0].scrollHeight - $('#scroll')[0].scrollTop <= $('#scroll')[0].offsetHeight);
    // display the message
    $('#scroll')[0].innerHTML += htmlMessage;
    // scroll down the scrollbar
    $('#scroll')[0].scrollTop = isScrolledDown ? $('#scroll')[0].scrollHeight : $('#scroll')[0].scrollTop;}
```

Or use to understand ajax and php [this book](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mylekha-ebook/IT%2B%2526%2BProgramming/PHP/AJAX-and-PHP,-2nd-Edition.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj4mJCe0PHRAhXBD8AKHdiGA6QQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNHc6XnGXjfbHHlWzFEjdr3Ci0I6FQ)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. While a link to a helpful external resource is always welcome, please also *quote a key excerpt* from the page you're linking to. This is so that if the website goes down or the page is (re)moved, then this answer won't become useless.